# Wordpress create thumbnails on demand

Tags: plugins, images, post-thumbnails

I am having a problem with my hosting as there are too many files in it. This is basically because of wordpress creating thumbnails for every image uploaded and this has accumulated over the last 3 years. I was wondering if there is a way of creating thumbnails for images that I intend to use on the homepage but on the single.php pages.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome. Check Regenerate thumbnail plugin https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

Comment: @Hector that will recreate thumbnails, what the OP is asking is for no thumbnails until the image is requested. Sadly that would likely require some sort of service running in the background to generate them on the fly as those folders are server directly by Nginx/Apache not WP itself

Comment: Daniel, how many files do you have? Can you tell us more about the original problem rather than the solution you've asked about?